# Copy row data to multiple other cells

Tags: multiple-data

What's the best way to allow users to easily copy data from one cell and apply it to other cells, without using key combinations?

I was thinking about dragging cell borders horizontally or vertically to apply data to adjacent cells, but the cell is also a drop-down, so I don't know how to activate those borders without expanding the drop-down.

Context: this is a form to request new hires with different schedules.

[image]

Comment: You can make a button "Apply to other days" which would copy the data to other cells. I 've seen such a thing somewhere.

Comment: What is the user goal of the dropdown-menu? If i understand it correctly, it's about gathering schedules for which new hires can apply? What about utilizing the Google Calendar drag-feature for creating time blocks and creating a week-calendar view for each unique hire?

Comment: We will write about it Emilia, but in the meantime, here is a summary of our live one-hour design session yesterday (https://youtu.be/iVW7IupP5XI) where me and my partner attempted to your answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jtiYCzqsEo

Answer (score 0):

First Highlight the Cells you want to copy to , then use single paste function

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a copy button, which freezes the current row (changes inputs boxes to labels), then the user can drag the cell or row (or multiple selection of cells from the row).

If using on a non-touch device, consider using the modifier keys (e.g. Shift, Ctrl on Windows) to reduce buttons in UI e.g. choose between options e.g. include this cell or not.